# Can't pass @Input variable in Angular 5 npm package (created using ng-packagr)

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, angular5, ng-packagr

I created npm package from Angular 5 project, using ng-packagr, and now  I'm trying to install that package in new project. I'm including package in NgModule of new project and using it like this:

```
  <created-package 
    [input1]="'value1'"
    [input2]="'value2'"  
  >
  </created-package>
```

This component renders, html and included css are shown, but @Input fields (input1 and input2) are UNDEFINED.

This is the example of my component.ts:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'created-package',
  templateUrl: './created-package.component.html'
})

export class CreatedPackage implements OnInit {
  @Input() value1: any;
  @Input() value2: any;


  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.value1, this.value2);

  }
}
```

It console.logs undefined..

If anyone knows the answer, I will be very grateful for reply! Thanks!

Comment: I think you should remove the single quotes in the HTML template so: `[input1]="'value1'"` becomes `[input1]="value1"`

Comment: @JDTLH9 that would only work if a property is defined on the parent component called `value1`, otherwise it would cause a compilation error.

Comment: @UncleDave agreed and that is clearly the case in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Your input variables inside component should have a matching name with what is passed in html, or you could pass alias name to **@Input()**.

either change:

```
 <created-package 
    [value1]="'value1'"
    [value2]="'value2'"  
 >
 </created-package>
```

or:

```
@Input('input1') value1: any;
@Input('input2') value2: any;
```